# Code complete for AngularJS constants/value injectables

Tags: json, angularjs, adobe-brackets

Is there a tool or extension for Brackets, allowing for proper code complete using AngularJS `angular.module().constant` or `angular.module().value` injectables? Here is an example:

**File 1**

```
   angular.module("app").constant({
     Person: {
        firstname: "Barry",
        lastname: "Sanders",
        position: "RB"
        }
    });
```

**File 2**

```
angular.module("app").factory(function(Person) {

       /* 
         I would like to type Person.la and have 
         Brackets suggest Person.lastname for me 
        */
       console.log(Person.lastname); 
});
```

The default code complete works kinda but usually ends up giving me a list of everything possible instead of what's associated with the given object. (Please ignore the improper use of the .factory() service. I used it strictly to illustrate the question)

Comment: What do you mean by "code complete"? Do you really mean intellisense?

Comment: Yeah, that's another term for it. The main point is to have it for services/constants across multiple files. Brackets (and some plugins) do pretty well if things are in the same file.